# How do I reference a unique index that uses a function in ON CONFLICT?

Tags: postgresql, upsert

I'm using postgres 9.5.3, and I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE packages (
  id   SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR NOT NULL
);
```

I have defined a function, `canonical_name`, like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION canonical_name(text) RETURNS text AS $$
    SELECT replace(lower($1), '-', '_')
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

I've added a unique index to this table that uses the function:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_package_name
ON packages (canonical_name(name));
CREATE INDEX
# \d+ packages
                                                  Table "public.packages"
 Column |       Type        |                       Modifiers                       | Storage  | Stats target | Description
--------+-------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id     | integer           | not null default nextval('packages_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              |
 name   | character varying | not null                                              | extended |              |
Indexes:
    "packages_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_package_name" UNIQUE, btree (canonical_name(name::text))
```

And this unique index is working as I expect; it prevents insertion of duplicates:

```
INSERT INTO packages (name) 
VALUES ('Foo-bar');

INSERT INTO packages (name) 
VALUES ('foo_bar');

ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_package_name"
DETAIL:  Key (canonical_name(name::text))=(foo_bar) already exists.
```

My problem is that I want to use this unique index to do an upsert, and I can't figure out how I need to specify the conflict target. [The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html) seems to say I can specify an index expression:

```
where conflict_target can be one of:

    ( { index_column_name | ( index_expression ) } [ COLLATE collation ] [ opclass ] [, ...] ) [ WHERE index_predicate ]
    ON CONSTRAINT constraint_name
```

But all of these things below that I've tried produce errors as shown, instead of a working upsert.

I've tried matching the index expression as I specified it:

```
INSERT INTO packages (name)
VALUES ('foo_bar')
ON CONFLICT (canonical_name(name)) 
DO UPDATE SET name = EXCLUDED.name;

ERROR:  there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification
```

Matching the index expression as `\d+` showed it:

```
INSERT INTO packages (name)
VALUES ('foo_bar')
ON CONFLICT (canonical_name(name::text)) 
DO UPDATE SET name = EXCLUDED.name;


ERROR:  there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification
```

Just naming the column that the unique index is on:

```
INSERT INTO packages (name)
VALUES ('foo_bar')
ON CONFLICT (name) 
DO UPDATE SET name = EXCLUDED.name;

ERROR:  there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification
```

Using the index name instead:

```
INSERT INTO packages (name)
VALUES ('foo_bar')
ON CONFLICT (index_package_name) 
DO UPDATE SET name = EXCLUDED.name;

ERROR:  column "index_package_name" does not exist
LINE 3: ON CONFLICT (index_package_name)
```

So how *do* I specify that I want to use this index? Or is this a bug?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Important note:** This behavior can only be observed on versions before 9.5.4. This is a bug that was fixed in 9.5.4. The rest of the answer describes the buggy behavior:

As you found out, you can only specify the expression for a unique *constraint* and not the one for a unique *index*.
This is somewhat confusing because under the hood a unique constraint is just a unique index (but that is considered an implementation detail).

To make matters worse for you, you cannot define a unique constraint over a unique index that contains expressions – I am not certain what the reason is, but suspect the SQL standard.

One way you can do this would be to add an artificial column, filled with the “canonical name” by a trigger and define the constraint on that column. I admit that that is not nice.

The correct solution, however, is to upgrade to the latest minor release for PostgreSQL 9.5.

Comment: After some experimentation, (with promoted indexes and check constraints using a function) I think the *artificial column* is the only workaround.

Comment: BTW, not sure about 9.5.3 but on 9.5.4 the `ON CONFLICT (canonical_name(name))` variant works fine. `PostgreSQL 9.5.4 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2, 64-bit`

Comment: @Abelisto: damn: I thought I tested to test on 9.5 #head, but it appers to be 9.5.2 ...

Comment: Laurenz: Thank you for your detailed answer, you are correct for postgres <= 9.5.3, and your answer might be the most helpful for people unable to upgrade. @Abelisto: I upgraded to postgres 9.6beta2 (next version available in homebrew right now) and confirmed that ON CONFLICT (canonical_name(name)) worked great! If you add your comment as an answer instead, I'd be happy to accept it!

Comment: I don't understand, the current doc (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html) clearly state that you can use numerous options for constraint_name, including index names.

Comment: @Pak Yes, but it must be an index that implements a unique constraint. You cannot use an arbitrary unique index name.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe could you please explain how to achieve `ON CONFLICT` behaviour for unique index in postgres 11.6  

`ON CONFLICT (unique_index_name)` doesn't work with error:
ERROR:  column "unique_index_name" does not exist
 

`ADD CONSTRAINT unique_constraint_name 
UNIQUE USING INDEX unique_index_name;`

doesnt work because of 
ERROR:  index "unique_index_name" contains expressions
 
  index definirtion is:  
<br/>`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_index_name ON ******(****, coalesce(f2, 0), coalesce(f3, 0));`

Comment: @gstackoverflow As I said, read [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html).